# How do I create a redirect after using pathauto_node_update_alias()

Tags: redirection, path-aliases, batch-operations

I am using the [Redirect](https://drupal.org/project/redirect) module.  I have a feature, where I have an update hook, that updates (and fixes) the path alias of the nodes on the site (after I made a change to the pathauto pattern).  I need to create a redirect, as updating the path alias does not do this for you when you use `pathauto_node_update_alias()`.  How do I go about this.  Below is the code I have:

```
function uw_cfg_redirect_update_7010(&$sandbox) {
  $query = "SELECT nid FROM {node} where status = 1";

  // If this is the first pass through this update function then set some variables.
  if (!isset($sandbox['total'])) {
    $result = db_query($query);
    $sandbox['total'] = $result->rowCount();
    $sandbox['current'] = 0;
  }

  // How many nodes should be processed per pass. The higher this number is, the faster your update will
  // complete, but the more likely your server will run out of memory or timeout.
  $nodes_per_pass = 50;

  // Get the nodes to process during this pass.
  $result = db_query_range($query, $sandbox['current'], $nodes_per_pass);
  while ($row = $result->fetchAssoc()) {
    $node = node_load($row['nid']);
    pathauto_node_update_alias($node);

    // TODO: [need to add redirect code here]

    // Increment "current" by 1.
    $sandbox['current']++;
  }

  // Set the value for finished. If current == total then finished will be 1, signifying we are done.
  // If not then this function will be trigger again.  See Drupal Batch API for more details.
  $sandbox['#finished'] = ($sandbox['current'] / $sandbox['total']);

  if ($sandbox['#finished'] === 1) {
    drupal_set_message(t('We processed @nodes nodes. DONE!!!', array('@nodes' => $sandbox['total'])));
    return t('Finish rewrite the path of all the nodes.');
  }

  return $sandbox;
}
```

Note:  This is not a problem if you use [Global Redirect](https://drupal.org/project/globalredirect) module.   This is not a problem when you resave a node, as redirect gets added.

Answer (score 0):

I'd have a look at [redirect_path_update](http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions!redirect!redirect.module/function/redirect_path_update/7) and [hook_path_update](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!path!path.api.php/function/hook_path_update/7) and maybe consider using node_save() instead of writing the paths directly.

If you're going to write them directly with pathauto_node_update_alias(), you may as well just write paths aliases and redirects directly to the database instead of wasting time node_load()ing all the nodes.